# Find the set of $y_0$ such that the IVP has no/one/two solutions on $(x_o,\infty)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification

Now:

The IVP is $y\frac{dy}{dx} = 1, y(x_0) = y_0$, this has solutions

$y(x) = \pm\sqrt{2x+y_0^2 - 2x_0}$

for the no solutions part

we have to find all $y_0$ where $2x+y_0^2-2x_0 < 0$

but there is no $y_0$ such that this is true since $x_0 < x $ on the interval in question so we get that $y_0^2 < 0$ this is no good.

So is the net in question the empty set?

For the one solution on the interval in question, we just need $2x+y_0^2-2x_0 = 0$ again, this gives the empty set since there is no $y_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $y_0^2 = 2(x_0 - x) < 0 $

For the 2 solutions, it turns out that we can choose any real number $y_0$ I fallen in to a trap here?
Or made a huge/trivial mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your analysis is almost correct, but you forgot about the $\pm$ sign. That is, the sign of $y_0$ determines which solution branch you have to take. One of the branches will start at $(x_0,y_0)$, while the other one starts at $(x_0,-y_0)$. So, while the ODE might provide you with two possible solution branches to choose from, the initial value problem always uniquely determines which branch you should take.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Frits, where did I forget the +- sign??

Comment: Well, you didn't forget to place it somewhere, you forgot *about* it. That is, you forgot that the initial conditions determine the solution branch, yielding a (one) unique solution.